# Connections on principal and associated fiber bundles exercises

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I am currently learning about principal and associated fiber bundles, and connections on these bundles, but I haven't been able to find a lot of exercises to solve in this topics.

I am using mainly the Kobayashi and Nomizu book "Foundations of differential geometry" and Jeffrey Lee's "Manifolds and differential geometry". The later has some more exercises to solve, but they are quite few.

I'd be thankful for any recommendation of books/classnotes containing exercises on this topics. I am principally interested in the Ehresmann kind of connection and in the induced connections on associated vector bundles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Differential Geometry
Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes
by Tu, Loring W.   https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319550824

Comment: Curvature and Characteristic Classes
by 
Johan L. Dupont https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0065364 Also, https://data.math.au.dk/publications/ln/2003/imf-ln-2003-69.pdf Once I have solved many problems and written somewhere on this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already checked Tu's book, and his approach is really clear and complete. I'm going to check the others as well. Thanks again!